# make border in Excel Cell using C#

Tags: c#, excel, border, cell

I have a little question, using C# I want text be in cell and not out of the cell. Because sometimes the text is too long and it goes automatically to another cells. How can I make border there? Should I use `Excel.Range.Borders`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for **wrapping text in your cell**

Here is some piece of code to do this:

```
sheet.Range["G3"].IsWrapText = true;
```

[Source and further info](http://janewdaisy.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/how-to-wrap-text-in-excel-cell-with-cvb-net/)

Comment: That's actually a nice (and probably correct) interpretation of the question +1

Comment: wooww great. I have one question more, how can I wrap the text that it doesn't go to another line but hide after border? `IsWrapText` makes my text goes to another lines if it reached the border

Comment: @UniLe: with `UsWrapText`, the text will be forced to go to a new line when the border is met. The only way (as far as I know) to "hide" your data is to have some content in the next cell (the first cell on the right)